# complex numbers in sympy: resolving Euler's Identity

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers, simplify

I am working with complex functions in sympy (python 3) and am having trouble getting sympy to simplify the equations.  In particular I can't get sympy to use Euler's Identity to break up the complex exponential into real and imaginary parts.  Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import I, init_printing

# setup printing
init_printing()

# complex potential cylinder in uniform flow
U,z,R,theta=sym.symbols('U z R theta')
F=U*z+U/z

# complex velocity cylinder in uniform flow
compVel=sym.diff(F,z)
exp1=sym.sympify('R*exp(I*theta)')
compVel=compVel.subs(z,exp1)
print(compVel)
phi,psi=sym.symbols('phi psi')
phi=sym.re(compVel)
psi=sym.im(compVel)
print(phi)
print(psi)
```

When I run this code the output is:

```
U - U*exp(-2*I*theta)/R**2
re(U) - re(U*exp(-2*I*theta)/R**2)
im(U) - im(U*exp(-2*I*theta)/R**2)
```

Am I missing something or is sympy not powerful enough to do recognize this simplification?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sympy assumes that all variables are complex, therefore it correctly returns the real part of `compVel` in terms of the real part of `U`, `R`, etc. If you declare the variables as reals by `U,z,R,theta=sym.symbols('U z R theta', real = True)`, sympy returns the expected output

Comment: @Stelios Should be the answer.

Comment: Actually it resolved the lone U but it did not resolve the exponential:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; @Stelios is correct but in addition when you use sympify you must pass a dictionary with the local variables that the expression contains.

```
exp1=sym.sympify('R*exp(I*theta)',locals={'R':R,'theta':theta})
```