# Sympy euler identity to two equations

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have an equation of the form:
^(2)+^(3)+^(4)+^(1)=0

In sympy, using the Euler identity I want to split it into two equations, one with real numbers and one imaginary.

cos(2)+cos(3)+cos(4)+cos(1)=0
sin(2)+sin(3)+sin(4)+sin(1)=0

So far I have tried:

```
a, b, c, d = symbols("a b c d")
theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4 = symbols("theta1 theta2 theta3 theta4")
eq1 = Eq(a*exp(I*theta2) + b*exp(I*theta3) + c*exp(I*theta4) +d*exp(I*theta1), 0) 
eq1 = eq1.subs([(a,40), (b,120), (c,80), (d,100), (theta1,0), (theta2, 40 * (pi.evalf()/180))])

lhs_real, lhs_img = eq1.lhs.as_real_imag()
rhs_real, rhs_img = eq1.rhs.as_real_imag()

eq2 = Eq(lhs_real, rhs_real)
eq3 = Eq(lhs_img, rhs_img)
```

However my eq2 seems to contain real and imaginary terms.
−120cos(**re**(3))sinh(**im**(3))+120cos(**re**(3))cosh(**im**(3))−80cos(**re**(4))sinh(**im**(4))+80cos(**re**(4))cosh(**im**(4))+130.641777724759=0

How can I achieve this with Sympy?
I have looked at this question [complex numbers in sympy: resolving Euler's Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270726/complex-numbers-in-sympy-resolving-eulers-identity) but the sympy.re and sympy.im will not work with Sympy equations.

Comment: I don't see any imaginary terms (note that `im(x)` is real). Presumably you want to create the symbols with `real=True` so that `im(x) = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome to SO!

If you want to separate expression into real and imaginary parts, you can only work with real variables (`real=True`). You're example could be rewritten as:

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()

a_r, b_r, c_r, d_r = sy.symbols('a_r, b_r, c_r, d_r', real=True) 
a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i = sy.symbols('a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i', real=True)
th1, th2, th3, th4 = sy.symbols('theta_1, theta_2, theta_3, theta_4 ', real=True)

# complex numbers:
a, b = (a_r + sy.I*a_i), (a_r + sy.I*a_i)
c, d =  (c_r + sy.I*c_i), (d_r + sy.I*d_i)

xpr0 = (a * sy.exp(sy.I*th2) + b * sy.exp(sy.I*th3) +
        c * sy.exp(sy.I*th4) + d * sy.exp(sy.I*th1))

eq1 = sy.Eq(sy.re(xpr0), 0)
# Gives: -aᵢ⋅sin(θ₂) + aᵣ⋅cos(θ₂) - bᵢ⋅sin(θ₃) + bᵣ⋅cos(θ₃) - cᵢ⋅sin(θ₄) + cᵣ⋅cos(θ₄) - dᵢ⋅sin(θ₁) + dᵣ⋅cos(θ₁) = 0

eq2 = sy.Eq(sy.im(xpr0), 0)
# Gives aᵢ⋅cos(θ₂) + aᵣ⋅sin(θ₂) + bᵢ⋅cos(θ₃) + bᵣ⋅sin(θ₃) + cᵢ⋅cos(θ₄) + cᵣ⋅sin(θ₄) + dᵢ⋅cos(θ₁) + dᵣ⋅sin(θ₁) = 0
```